# Increment counter sequentially inside CUDA kernel?

Tags: cuda, counter

I can't figure out this logic, so I have a counter `SOLUTIONS` which increments atomically every time I have a new solution per thread, but in some cases a single thread can find more than one solution, but in this case I would like it to increment the current value one more time. This logic seems simple, implemented by `atomicAdd`. But the problem is, I need to use that counter as an index for an array.

Example:

```
SOME_ARRAY[tid] = STUFF; // puts stuff in individual indexes because of thread id.
atomicAdd(SOLUTIONS, 1); // increments the max solutions found.
```

But now a single thread has found two solutions, I want it to increment AFTER the current MAX solution.

```
SOME_ARRAY[SOLUTIONS+1] = STUFF;
```

But as I understand, if two or more threads try to do it, it won't work? I need the second thread to be at SOLUTIONS+2 and not write the same location.

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: My try at the implementation, this still doesn't work because when I printf the offset both threads print the same number. And when I access the `d_PROGRESS` array `2` elements are always number `85` which is a random number that I never placed in there.

```
 __device__
 bool isSafe (int row, int col, int cmp_row, int cmp_col) {
    if ((col - cmp_col) == 0) {return 0;}
    if (abs(row - cmp_row) == abs(col - cmp_col)) {return 0;}
    return 1;
 }

 __global__
  void nqueensKernel(int row, int n, bool one, bool all, int pitch,
               Solution * d_solution,
               Solution * d_PROGRESS,
               Solution *d_PROGRESS_OUT,
               unsigned long long * NUM_THREADS,
               unsigned long long * NUM_SOLUTIONS) {

int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int isAlone = 0;
if (index == 0) {*NUM_THREADS = 0;}
__syncthreads();
if (row == 0) {
  d_PROGRESS_OUT[index * n + row] = index;
  atomicAdd(NUM_THREADS, 1);
}
else {
  int moresolutions = 0;
  for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < row; k++) {
      int checkcol = d_PROGRESS[index * n + k];
      isAlone = isSafe(row, col, k, checkcol);
      if (!isAlone) { /*printf("Is Alone? %d\n", isAlone);*/ break; }
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if ( isAlone ) {
      moresolutions++;
      if (moresolutions == 1) {
          d_PROGRESS_OUT[(index * n) + row] = col;
          atomicAdd(NUM_THREADS, 1);
          for (int o = 0; o < row; o++) {
            d_PROGRESS_OUT[(index * n) + o] = d_PROGRESS[(index * n) + o];
          }
      } else if (moresolutions > 1) {
          int offset = atomicAdd(NUM_THREADS, 1);
          d_PROGRESS_OUT[((offset+1) * n) + row] = col;
          for (int m = 0; m < row; m++) { d_PROGRESS_OUT[((offset+1) * n) + m] = d_PROGRESS[(index * n) + m]; }
      }
      if (row == n-1) { atomicAdd(NUM_SOLUTIONS, 1); }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please? I am doing this right now: `atomicAdd(SOL, 1); ANSWER[SOL] = ans;` but still get error for stuff that is assigned in the next line after `ANSWER[SOL] = ans;` which is also suppose to be the same index, but I am assuming `atomicAdd` changes the value by then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to reserve the storage in `SOME_ARRAY` using the value returned by `atomicAdd`, which is the *old* value that was stored in the variable *before* the add, and incrementing the atomic variable by *the number of slots* you want to reserve. For example:

```
int offset = atomicAdd(SOLUTIONS, number_of_solutions_found_by_this_thread);
SOME_ARRAY[offset] = stuff;
SOME_ARRAY[offset + 1] = more stuff;
...
SOME_ARRAY[offset + number_of_solutions_found_by_this_thread - 1] = also more stuff;
```

Assume `SOLUTIONS` is initially 0.

1. Some thread (which we will fondly call #27) finds 4 solutions, and executes the `atomicAdd`. It gets 0 back as a result, and `SOLUTIONS` is now 4.
2. Before #27 gets to the next line, thread #88 gets to the atomic add and increments `SOLUTIONS` by 9. It gets back `4` as a result and `SOLUTIONS` is now 13.
3. #27 proceeds to storing its solutions from index 0 to 3, no interference with #88.

This is a common pattern in many parallel algorithms that require aggregating variable-length results across threads.

Comment: Thank you much for your help so far. I tried that and it still gives me the same error (main question post edited). Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: It's suppose to brute force n-queens problem, but the solution I get always has one extra incorrect solution because it reads a value that was not initialized. Only reason that would happen is if I didn't place the value there in the first place (rest seems correct). And the code only isn't working when I have more solutions than 1 in a single thread. So, I assumed it was the `atomicAdd` offset thing still not working. Once again, thank you for your help! Would you like to see the whole code?

Comment: I did read the answer and the description, it makes sense now. :)

Comment: I don't think I can condense it to the point where it's compilable. I posted the kernel and the device function that I am using, I understand if that is too much. I appreciate the help anyways!